# I can't understand Why I can only connect to 8080 port in node Js express server

Tags: node.js, port, cloud9

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || '3000');

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello Express');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log(app.get('port'),'listening');
})
```

Hi, I started studying nodeJs but got a problem.

If I run the server this way,

```
$ node app.js
8080 Listening
```

There's no problem in connecting to this server.

However, I got a problem if I run the server after changing the port.

```
$ PORT=3001  node app.js                                                                                                                                                                                   
3001 Listening
```

It seems working without problem but I can't connect to `3001` port. So I tried other ports but neither worked. I can't understand why only `8080` port is available.

I'm developing by using `AWS cloud9` IDE and `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`.

Comment: Check if ports are blocked by the firewall

Comment: c9 has specific ports you can use, see docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html

Comment: Thank you! I never noticed it's because I was using c9.